# Blank fields in the db due to md5?

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I have a user registration form, and even when I enter nonempty text in the `<input>` fields, I find that upon submission of the form, the counterpart fields in the new row being created in the database are empty themselves (except for the password and hash fields).

2 things I think are key here:

1. This is only happening since I implemented **md5**.
2. This is only happening only in the live website. It works fine when testing with *Xampp*.

Specifically, in `send.php`:

```
<form action="receibe.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required/>
  <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" required/>
  <input type="tel" name="telefono" placeholder="TelÈfono (opcional)" />
  <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="Correo @" required/>
  <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" required />
  <input type="password" name="clave" placeholder="Clave" required/>
  <input type="submit" value="Registrarme" class="boton_enviar">
</form>
```

And then in `receive.php`:

```
if(!empty($_POST['nombre'])) { $nombre=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nombre']); }
if(!empty($_POST['apellido'])) { $apellido=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['apellido']); }
if(!empty($_POST['correo'])) { $correo=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['correo']); }
if(!empty($_POST['telefono'])) { $telefono=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telefono']); }
if(!empty($_POST['usuario'])) { $usuario=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']); }
if(!empty($_POST['clave'])) { $clave=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['clave']); }

$hash = md5( rand(0,1000) );

include("connection.php");

$consultar_usuario=mysql_query("SELECT usuario FROM registro WHERE usuario='$usuario'", $conectar);

if (mysql_num_rows($consultar_usuario)==0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO registro (nombre, apellido, correo, telefono, usuario, clave, hash) VALUES('$nombre', '$apellido', '$correo', '$telefono', '$usuario', '". md5($clave) ."', '$hash')", $conectar); }
```

So the fields that are blank in the new row being created in the database are the ones corresponding to *nombre*, *apellido*, *telefono*, *correo* and *usuario*. *Clave* stands for the password.

*Disclaimer*: Upon research of previous posts, I haven't found an answer for this specific problem (nor a close enough question). I am aware that **md5** is no longer recommended, still I am only interested in fixing this specific technical issue right now.

Comment: This whole thing is a horror show of worst practices, especially using the wickedly out of date `mysql_query` method. What is your goal here? What query string is being generated? What errors do you get? Honestly if you're even the least bit concerned about security, burn this code to the ground and do it over properly. At the **absolute least** use proper [password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) procedures.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the harsh feedback. I thought the last paragraph would do but sometimes it is not enough: Can you append your answer to my **specific question**? The 'error' is that instead of getting the submitted data, I get empty fields. Thanks

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but this kind of code is why personal information leaks from sites. Again: What query is generated? You need to give an example of the SQL code you're actually trying to run. The differences between your local machine and the server will be obvious then.

Comment: @tadman I appreciate your honesty, it's just that I am moving along the learning curve and only after getting this right I will consider the subject of msqli and the more reliable password hashing methods, etc. The code is an msql_query/insert, simple as that (bottom line in gray background). Please refer me to where to learn about the differences between my local machine and server as well, I will appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($_POST)` in receive.php and see what it shows? Also you only need to do `!empty()` the isset is not needed.

Comment: If you're just learning, that's fine, but do it right. Picking a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that suits your needs and style will help considerably, especially since Laravel has a built-in
[authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication) that does everything you want and more.

Comment: Please do not learn from outdated and insecure material. please, please, please. You're just harming yourself

Comment: @tadman thanks I will indeed pick a framework in the future, for the time being I want to toughen myself with the raw language, until I get a moderate sense of mastery.

Comment: @Berni There is nothing "raw" about the "mysql_*" interface. It's simply outdated. Learning it will only teach you bad habits.

Comment: @Berni There's nothing long with learning SQL, it's an important skill to have, but using `mysql_query` is completely the wrong way to go about doing that. Use Laravel and their query builder to get things done today and be productive, it'll guide you towards best practices and shield you from dangers, then learn more about how that works by digging deeper layer by layer. Starting at the bottom is like trying to learn how to drive by building a car from scratch, slow, painful, and dangerous. Unless you've driven before you don't even know what a car is supposed to do, so you'll get it wrong.

Comment: What are both PHP versions on your localhost and your remote host?

Comment: @sємsєм remote host is 5.3.29 and localhost is 5.6.3 (Note: remote host lets me pick 5.2, 5.3, 5.4 and 5.5)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `isset()` and `!empty()` just use `!empty()`. You also dont need to `mysql_string_escape()` twice. Change this and see. It has nothing to do with `md5()` but you should change to `sha1()` anyway.

A better approach would be to build your SQL string up to reflect the data available. As you have sensibly named your $_POST fields same as your database fields you can do something like this..

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO `registro`(";
$values = "VALUES(";
foreach($_POST as $field=>$value){
    $insert.="`".$field."`,"; //add a field 
    $values.="'".mysql_escape_string($value)."',"; //add a value
}
$insert = rtrim($insert,",").") "; //get rid of extra comma and close brackets
$values = rtrim($values,",").")"; //do same

$sql=$insert.$values;//use $sql in your query
echo $sql;//run it into phpmyadmin to test
```

This is all good for learning but if your code is going into production (as some of the commentators said) you should look to use a framework or library which will have solved all these problems for you and done a better job than I have above.

If this doesnt work please update your post showing the contents of $_POST by doing `print_r($_POST)` at the top of your script. Hard to debug until we have seen what is actually being sent in to the script.

Comment: I changed it as you say (removed the mysql_escape_string() from the SQL query) but same problem still.